# What is the value of undefined variable on shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I am creating an array from a file but I noticed that if I don't initialize a variable and use it then also it works fine. Like my code is:

```
while read line
   do 
    array[i]="$line"
    i=$i+1
   done < file
```

here I am wondering how the value of 'i' has been initialized with zero, even though I haven't initialized its value.

Comment: variable `i` isn't initialize, and you typed `i` and `$i`

Comment: That is my question, I have not initialized any value and even though it works fine. check this out and if you run ${#array[@]}, It will print the correct length of the array. 
How does bash handle it?

Comment: Strange, what should not work, it works...`array[i]`

Comment: You don't actually need `i` at all here. `array+=( "$line" )`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first tell you that this is not doing what you expect.  Uninitialized variables in bash will evaluate depending on the context.  To `0` where number is expected; to `an empty string` where string is expected.  In this case...

```
i=$i+1
```

is actually a string concatenation.  The whole thing works anyway because `+1` is different from `+1+1` etc.  What you meant is probably this:

```
: $((++i))
```

or this:

```
i=$((i + 1))
```

But anyway, using uninitialized variables is just a bad practice.  It useful in one-liners, where writing `i=0` or `i=""` is unnecessary burden, but in scripts I would use `set -u` at the beginning to catch all instances.

Some useful source: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Answer (score 1):

`i` has not been initialized to zero, but [its reference value evaluates to zero](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr):

> If the variable is empty (null) or unset, its reference evaluates to 0.

And in the following line, `i=$i+1`, the variable is replaced with its value (empty), leading to `i=+1`, which turns out to be equal to 1.

So it works mostly by accident, but leads to the expected result in this case.

In the future, I recommend using `set -u` to avoid accidentally using uninitialized variables.